# How do i say is not, is not

Tags: c#, boolean-expression

i don't want to say:

```
(trsaz != v1) && (trsaz != v2) && ...
```

i want something like:

```
trsaz != (v1, v4, v7, v11)
```

Is this possible or is there also something else besides `!=`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var badList = new[] { v1, v4, v7, v11 };
var result = !badList.Contains(trsaz);
```

Comment: How would i do this for controls passing through constructor: con.control.v1, con.control.v4, con.control.v7, con.control.v11 ?

Comment: you should be able to create an array like this `var badList = new[] { con.control.v1, con.control.v4, con.control.v7, con.control.v11 };` If not, can you post your constructor signature?

Comment: If you want to compare by name, then you can use

`var result =  !badList.Any(c => c.Name == trsaz.Name);`

Answer (score 2):

```
var excludeList = new[] { "v1", "v4", "v7", "v11" };
if(!excludeList.Contains(trsaz))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I prefer creating a little extension method for that:

```
public static bool IsIn<T>(this T obj, params T[] set) {
    return set.Any(el => element.Equals(obj));        
}
```

It encapsulates all the black magic and makes your code really concise which is your goal, obviously:

```
if (!trsaz.IsIn(v1, v4, v7, v11)) {
    // ...
}
```

It's always good to hide the mechanism if it's not important, especially in this case where the use of any mechanism is not necessary at all and will confuse some people who will maintain your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (new[] {v1, v4, v7}).Every(o => o != trsaz);
```